# LAMP Server: (104) Connection reset by peer

Tags: lamp

A user reported the following problem when attempting to visit www.airlinemogul.com.

---

The requested URL could not be retrieved

While trying to retrieve the URL: http://www.airlinemogul.com/airlinemogul/index.php

The following error was encountered:

```
* Read Error
```

The system returned:

```
(104) Connection reset by peer
```

An error condition occurred while reading data from the network. Please retry your request.

---

There are no other issues reported by any other users, so it may be an isolated issue. Could anyone give me any suggestions as to how I could investigate the problem further or find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The message means that the connection was dropped on your side without returning the expected data.

See if you can correlate the time to something like a server restart.  Eg, if you're using Apache, look at using { apachectl graceful } rather than { apachectl restart }; the former lets existing connections finish their work, the latter is more abrupt and might result in that message.  Does your log rotation system involve a server restart, for instance?

Check your server logs, looking for that address.  Check dmesg, to see if a component of your server crashed with a segfault.